# Attempted to load an infinite number of tiles while using proj4leaflet and EPSG:32614

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, angular, proj4leaflet

I get error "Attempted to load an infinite number of tiles" while using proj4leaflet and [EPSG:32614](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32614).

```
 crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:32614',
  '+proj=utm +zone=14N +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs', {
      resolutions: [
          8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128
      ],
      origin: [329370, 3970950],
      bounds: L.bounds([218128.7031, 6126002.9379], [1083427.2970, 7692850.9468])
  });

  options = {
     crs: this.crs,
    layers: [
      tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        { attribution: '...' })
      ],
      zoom: 16,
      center: [329370, 3970950],
      attributionControl: false,
  };
```

Comment: Where did you get info that this map uses EPSG:32614? A look at https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer shows it uses standard Mercator 3857.